# Android no suitable constructor found for HeaderItem(int,String,<null>)

Tags: java, android, television

I'm a bigginer in android i want to create one app for mobile and TV,
When i try to build project i see error:

**Error:(156, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for HeaderItem(int,String,)
constructor HeaderItem.HeaderItem(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor HeaderItem.HeaderItem(long,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)**

In my MainFragment.java the code is like this:

```
  private void loadRows() {
    List<Movie> list = MovieList.setupMovies();

    mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
    mCardPresenter = new CardPresenter();

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            Collections.shuffle(list);
        }
        ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mCardPresenter);
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
            listRowAdapter.add(list.get(j % 5));
        }
        HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(i, MovieList.MOVIE_CATEGORY[i], null);
        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
    }

    HeaderItem gridHeader = new HeaderItem(i, "PREFERENCES", null);

    GridItemPresenter mGridPresenter = new GridItemPresenter();
    ArrayObjectAdapter gridRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mGridPresenter);
    gridRowAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.grid_view));
    gridRowAdapter.add(getString(R.string.error_fragment));
    gridRowAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.personal_settings));
    mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(gridHeader, gridRowAdapter));

    setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);

}
```

Please help me

Thanks to all

Comment: just remove the null pointer in your call to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HeaderItem` public constructor only takes either **one** argument `(String name)` or **two** arguments `(long id, String name)`. You currently have three. Remove the third argument `null`.

Refer to Android Developers documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HeaderItem.html).